# Phusion Passenger Sub URI sym link problems

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, passenger

I am deploying a sub URI rails app on Ubuntu with Apache and Phusion Passenger to

```
www.mydomain.com/suburi
```

and am having issues with getting it configured. Right now I am getting this error:

```
Passenger Error #2
An error occurred while trying to access '/srv/www/mydomain/public/suburi': Cannot resolve possible symlink '/srv/www/mydomain/public/suburi': No such file or directory (2)
```

Both the rails app for mydomain.com and the rails app for mydomain.com/suburi reside in /srv/www/

My current virtual Host looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost 173.230.137.212:80> 
  ServerName www.mydomain.com
  ServerAlias mydomain.com
  DocumentRoot /srv/www/mydomain/public
  ErrorLog /srv/www/error.log
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteOptions Inherit
  RailsEnv production

<directory /srv/www/mydomain/public>
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
  AllowOverride all
  Order allow,deny 
  allow from all
</directory>

RailsBaseURI /suburi                   
<Directory /srv/www/suburi>
  Options -MultiViews               
</Directory>
```

I know the paths are correct, but that's the only thing I know is correct. My server administration skills are not amazing.

I made a sym link from the mydomain.com's public folder to the sub uri's public folder. Not sure if I did this right, I found the documentation to not be so great. Is there anything I'm missing and/or doing wrong? Did I make the wrong system link?

I would really appreciate some help.

Or for that matter, if anyone knows a better/easier way to do it with a sub domain, like subdomain.mywebsite.com that would work too.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

If you use suburi-s, then

1. `<documentroot>/<suburi>` is meant to point to the public dir of your rails app
2. your rails app root dir is meant to be one directory above your rails app public

Both are solved if you got a dedicated public docroot for your domain, and then you do

```
ln -sf /path/to/suburi-rails-app/public <documentroot>/<suburi>
```

The documentation is indeed not so great. So your solution would be:

```
ln -sf /srv/www/suburi/public srv/www/mydomain/public/suburi
```

and the vhost conf:

```
<VirtualHost 173.230.137.212:80> 

  ServerName www.mydomain.com
  ServerAlias mydomain.com
  DocumentRoot /srv/www/mydomain/public
  ErrorLog /srv/www/error.log
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteOptions Inherit
  RailsEnv production

  <Directory /srv/www/mydomain/public>
    Options FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
    Order allow,deny 
    Allow from all
  </Directory>

  RailsBaseURI /suburi                   
  <Directory /srv/www/mydomain/public/suburi>
    Options -MultiViews               
  </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

you say that: Both the rails app for mydomain.com and the rails app for mydomain.com/suburi reside in /srv/www/

This confused me a bit, I don't think it is a good idea to want to run an app on a domain and another on a suburi, since routing is bound to be confused.
Rather use 2 suburi-s, in which case do

```
ln -sf /srv/www/suburi2/public srv/www/mydomain/public/suburi2
```

where /srv/www/suburi2 is your second applications root dir, and add:

```
RailsBaseURI /suburi2                   
<Directory /srv/www/mydomain/public/suburi2>
  Options -MultiViews               
</Directory>
```

you can add any number of suburis to the same vhost.

hope this helped

Comment: As for 2 above: if your rails app root is not 'above' that app's public dir, normally you can specify the PassengerAppRoot, however, this is not an option per suburi, so not sure what if I want a different app root dir...